# binding an object into a control of wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new in WPF and I would like to have a quick advice on how to bind this object to a wpf control and I dont know which control should I use:

```
public class Parent
{
  public string Name{get; set;}
  public List<Child> Childs {get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
  public string Name{get; set;}
  public int Age {get; set;}
}

public class ParentFactory
{
   public List<Parent> Parents {get; set;}

   public ParentFactory()
   {
      Child child1 = new Child() {Name="Peter", Age=10;};
      Child child2 = new Child() {Name="Mary", Age=9;};
      Child child3 = new Child() {Name="Becky", Age=12;};

      Parent parent1 = new Parent(){Name="Adam", Childs = new List<Child<>(){child1, child2}};
      Parent parent2 = new Parent(){Name="Kevin", Childs = new List<Child<>(){child3}};

      Parents = new List<Parent>(){parent1, parent2};
   }
}
```

After creating this instance:

ParentFactory parentFactory = new ParentFactory();

I would like to bind the parentFactory.Parents() to a control in WPF. I would expect to see something like this:

---

Adam

-- Peter, 10

-- Mary, 9

Kevin

-- Becky, 12

---

They are all displayed on textboxes and I can change them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The nature of the problem seems to induce that every Parent is also a Child, and that these should be displayed in a [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.aspx).

Comment: you probably need a treeview. Here is explained how to use treeviews in WPF with databinding http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

Comment: Implement [INotifyPropertyChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) on Parent and Child or on a base class and derive from it.

Comment: it does not need to be a treeview. is there any control that can be used directly with WPF>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a TreeView with a HierarchicalDataTemplate.

Note however that without implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your model, your bindings won't update on any property changes. Also, without replacing your lists with ObservableCollections, your view won't update as you add more items to the list.

Something like this should work, first define your templates:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Parent}" ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Child}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <TextBlock>, </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then you can use them with a TreeView like this (assuming Parents is a property in the DataContext of the TreeView):

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}"/>
```

If you don't want a TreeView, you can easily do something list this with a ListView, change you DataTemplates to this:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Parent}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Child}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <TextBlock>, </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And then you can bind it like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}"/>
```

Note: You'll probably want to fiddle around with the styles a little because out-of-the-box, this looks a bit crap. You'll probably want to, at least, indent the child ListView (the one defined in the Parent DataTemplate) and get rid of it's border.

Also Note: the StackPanel to layout multiple TextBlocks for the name and age isn't ideal either, but it's quick and dirty. You might want to handle that differently. You could use a (multi) converter to format it, use StringFormat or add another property to your model just for display, or even just override ToString on the child class.

**Another Edit**

A quick (and ugly) example of using the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This puts a data grid inside a data grid using the row details template. If you click a row, it'll display the children as row details. If you want details always available, you can remove the RowDetailsTemplate and replace the DataGridTextColumn with a DataGridTemplateColumn and then define a template for you data.

Comment: is there something that I can use with Grid: <Textbox> with binding?

Comment: @devn: If you don't want a TreeView you can use an ListView. It won't work automatically with a HieracrchicalDataTemplate however, so what you'll have to do is set the DataTemplate for your Parent to include another ListView for your children.

Comment: @devn: And yes, you can replace the TextBlocks with TextBox if you want and specify two-way binding. But note the earlier comments about implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Although if this is the *only* place you bind these values and this is the *only* way these values can change, you can probably get away without bothering with INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: a great answer! Thanks a lot. Just curious if there is a DataGrid control that I can use without using ListView like in asp.net. is there such a control?

Comment: @devn: Yes, you could use a DataGrid if you want. The templating is handled slightly differently, but you can do it.

Comment: could you please so kind to post an answer using DataGrid as well? I will be greatly appreciated about it. I am learning it so I would like to see the alternatives. thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please also give me an answer how to do it using DataGrid? Thanks in advance

Comment: @devn: there are a bunch of ways you could do this. You could use DataGridTemplateColumns and/or RowDetailsTemplates to present this kind of data. It's up to you to decide what solution works best for you. I'll try and add a simple example.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't wish a tree view (which is probably best as you have a hierarchy - though it's a one-level deep only, so you might still have a case for a list)...
you could do something like this (that's a rough outline, you should fill in the dots)...

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllNodes}">
</ItemsControl>
```

...and have templates defined for each type specifically, like Matt mentioned also...

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type namespace:Child}">
...
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type namespace:Parent}">
...
</DataTemplate>
```

...while the `AllNodes` is a list you need to `flatten` from the hierarchy you have, you can use this...

```
var allnodes = Parents.SelectMany(p => new object[]{p}.Concat(p.Childs));
```

...and expose AllNodes as a property similar to Parents - you just need a View Model with properly implemented INotifyPropertyChanged as suggested.

hope this helps

Comment: great answer. Using ItemsControl is better. Thanks a lot!

Comment: when using ItemControl, if there are rows when I click on an item, the whole row is selected. how can I disable it? or there is another controller better than the ItemsControl?

Comment: wouldn't say better :) maybe easier - hierarchy is more powerful and @Matt -s right on target with how this should be handled. ItemsControl doesn't 'Select' things - ListBox does that - so just use ItemsControl and you should be fine. Here is a link on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069374/how-to-highlight-selected-item-in-itemscontrol