# Getting selected item in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have the following code which populates my user control in form of rows and column. The user control which is being populated contains Button, links, textbox etc. When a certain button is pressed on a particular User Control in a particular row/column, I need to know for which User Control that button was pressed. Here is the XAML that is populating the user controls in rows and columns

```
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Templates}" Width="{Binding GridWidth}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding NumColumns}" />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                 <Style>
                     <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}" />
                     <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowIndex}" />
                  </Style>
                 </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
```

Templates is basically a collection of UserControls that are being populated in Rows/Columns.
Preferably I want to do this in ViewModel but solution in code behind for now will work as well.

Comment: An `ItemsControl` does not track the selected item. If you want that behavior, use something like a `ListBox` and overwrite the template, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9069382/302677)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`ItemsControl` can't select items, only present collections. Only a [Selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.aspx) or one of it's descendants can select items.

For your scenario, I think a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750972.aspx) with [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752213.aspx) would fit. When the user would click a control in the line, the event would bubble to the `ListView` and the item would get selected. You can override the default styles so it wouldn't display as selected line: [WPF ListView turn off selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051215/wpf-listview-turn-off-selection).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ListView`, and add a `SelectionChanged` event. Then you implement a function to verify `ListView.SelectedItem` just like a `DataGrid`

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution for you...a behavior:

```
   public static class SelectedItemBehavior
   {
      public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingProperty =
         DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Binding", typeof(object), typeof(SelectedItemBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new object(),
               FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
               SelectedItem_Changed));

      public static object GetBinding(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
      {
         return (object)frameworkElement.GetValue(BindingProperty);
      }

      public static void SetBinding(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, object value)
      {
         frameworkElement.SetValue(BindingProperty, value);
      }

      private static void SelectedItem_Changed(Object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
         ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton)sender;
         toggleButton.Checked -= ToggleButtonOnChecked;
         toggleButton.IsChecked = e.NewValue?.Equals(toggleButton.DataContext) ?? false;
         toggleButton.Checked += ToggleButtonOnChecked;
      }

      private static void ToggleButtonOnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
         ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton)sender;
         SetBinding(toggleButton, toggleButton.DataContext);
      }
   }
```

Then bind as follows:

```
    <ItemsControl
        Name="ItemsControlList"
        Width="200"
        Height="100"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton local:SelectedItemBehavior.Binding="{Binding ElementName=ItemsControlList, Path=DataContext.SelectedValue}" Content="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```