# Refer to value from ItemControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a itemscontrol as below

```
   <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl Name="PlannerItemControl" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Name="MainGrid" Style="{StaticResource VisibleKey}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Name="lblTimeText" Content="{Binding ID}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Name="lblTime2" Content="{Binding ID}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Is it possible to retrieve the value of ID from the itemscontrol outside of the itemscontrol? Basically I want the value of Label lblTimeText in label lblTime2. Please help.

Comment: Have you set ID to use NotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel? then your binding should work

Comment: @VisualBean Yes I have. It works as expected in lblTimeText but please note that itemsouce of PlannerItemControl is a ObservableCollection set in the code.

Comment: Ahh so your looking for a selectedItem.ID or are there multiple lbltime2?

Comment: @VisualBean Yes I am looking for selectedItem.ID outside the itemscontrol. There is only one lblTime2- don't understand 'are there mutiple lblTime2'

Comment: ItemsControl doesn't track selectedItem - thus I thought you might have multiple labels to fill (wierd, but what the heck :)) - see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456836/gettting-selected-item-in-itemscontrol

Comment: @VisualBean Thanks for that. Assuming that I changing the ItemsControl to ListBox, how would lblTime2 refer to selecteditem?

Answer (score 1):

The ItemsControl does not track SelectedItem - instead use a ListBox.
(The selectedItem should be the same type as your collection items).

To track a selectedItem you need to bind the selectedItem property of the listbox to a property in your ViewModel

```
<Listbox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding YourItem}">
```

(remember INotifyChanged)

and then bind that item.id to your label

```
 <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Name="lblTime2" Content="{Binding YourItem.ID}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```