# Changing Textblock background in WPF resetting itself after color change

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a textblock in a WPF usercontrol defined as:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
           Text="{Binding RecognitionResults}"
           Background="{Binding ResultBackground}" />
```

The `UserControl` in which the `TextBlock` is displayed is being presented as a `String` from another `UserControl` as:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}" >
      <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style>
                <Setter Property="Control.Margin"
                        Value="{Binding Margin}"/>
           </Style>
      </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
 </ItemsControl>
```

Essentially, the `ItemsControl` is presenting a list of "Strings", each string itself being represented by its own `UserControl`.

Now, when I Tap on the display of the `TextBlock`, the gesture performs this action to change the background color from yellow to green in the ViewModel:

```
public void Refill()
{
    ResultBackground = Brushes.Green;
}
```

The `ResultBackground` color is defined in the ViewModel as:

```
 private SolidColorBrush resultbackground =
     (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#FFEFF100");

 public SolidColorBrush ResultBackground
 {
      get
      {
           Console.WriteLine("Now getting resultbackground of "
               + resultbackground);
           return resultbackground;
      }
      set
      {
          if (resultbackground != value)
          {
              resultbackground = value;
              OnPropertyChanged("ResultBackground");
          }
      }
 }
```

So, when I physically tap on the `TextBlock`, the gesture will successfully turn it from yellow to green. So far so good.

However, when I execute the `Refill()` method from a command (i.e., a menu command), the `TextBlock` first turns the green (like it should) but then redisplays as the initial yellow. Watching the output from the `Console.WriteLine` above confirms that the get is first called to turn the box green from `Refill()`, but then (there is no stack trace), the get is called again (without the set being called) that retrieves yellow!

I am at a complete loss as to why this is happening or what to do to fix it. The only places in code where `ResultBackground` is even referenced is in the above code.

Any help in getting this to work would be most appreciated.

Edit: I don't know if it is relevant or not, but the command that executes refill() is being executed as an Action from the menu as:

```
 <UserControl x:Class="Nova5.UI.Views.Ink.InkView"
        ............................

<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
         <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding OnSelected}" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>


<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:MyMenuItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubItems}">
            <ContentPresenter
                Content="{Binding Path=DisplayText}"
                RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Menu Grid.Row="3" Height="28" >
        <MenuItem Header="Options" ItemsSource="{Binding OptionSubItems}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding DisplayText}" >
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Command"  Value="{Binding OnSelected}"/>
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

</Grid>
```

Where OptionSubItems is built in the viewmodel constructor as:

```
  OptionSubItems = new ObservableCollection<MyMenuItem>();
```

and MyMenuItem is:

```
   public class MyMenuItem : MenuItemBase
{
    private Action Command;

    public MyMenuItem(String DisplayText, Action command)
    {
        this.DisplayText = DisplayText;

        this.Command = command;
    }
    public override void OnItemSelected()
    {
        this.Command();
    }
}
```

The ViewModel constructor dynamically builds the command list as:

```
    OptionSubItems.Add(new MyMenuItem("Refill", delegate()
        {
            CurrentViewModelDetails.ExecuteMenuCommand("Refill");
        }));
```

and ExecuteMenuCommand does:

```
     if (commandname == "RefillAllCurrentPrescriptions")
        {

            for (int k = 0; k < Strings.Count; k++)
            {
                Strings[k].refill();
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps.  (I wondering if the problem is in the above xaml with two bindings to the OnSelected from different styles?)

Comment: Can you post the complete viewmodel code.

Comment: 1. Don't put View related stuff into your ViewModel, it's violation of MVVM pattern. 2. Where are you binding `refill()`and why it's a common method instead of an `ICommand` or `DelegateCommand` (or whatever your framework calls it)? We usually don't bind methods/actions directly into XAML but use commands and `INotifyPropertyChanged ` (which you seem to have implemented)

Comment: you should maybe look into doing it with a `ListBox` style instead, as it's a bad practice to handle styling via the ViewModel.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069374/how-to-highlight-selected-item-in-itemscontrol

Comment: @Tseng refill() is not bound to the xaml. It is a method called in the viewmodel that changes the property ResultBackground that is bound to the view. Having the view bound with properites in the viewmodel is correct, right? As above, INotifyPropertyChanged is used and the refill() operation is called from a command placed in the menu. Thanks.

Comment: @Staeff  does such styling have anything to do with the textblock reseting to the initial yellow color?

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian I could post the complete viewmodel, but each usercontrol has its own viewmodel and the code is quit extensive. What part would you like? (I've tried to be concise with the above post). Thanks.

Comment: What I feel is it is getting reset somewhere?

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian My guess is the same. The interesting thing is that when placing a breakpoint on the get{} for ResultBackground, there Is a stack trace from the refill() call, but no trace when it gets reset which makes me think it coming directly from the xaml. Ideas?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you bind it using a OneWay binding? Perhaps something cached in the UI is resetting the background color to it's original value

Comment: @Rachel Nope. Just tried. I get the same momentary green background before it is reset to the initial yellow.

Comment: @AlanWayne Is there any chance the Refill method is being executed from a background thread or at a different priority? I've sometimes had issues with bindings that get updated on another thread, or at a different priority. You could try using the `Dispatcher` to ensure the color change happens on the UI thread at a Normal priority.

Comment: @Rachel Great idea! What would you use for the Dispatcher call and where to place it? Much thanks.

Comment: @AlanWayne I would just try calling `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Refill)` from your command, or even `....BeginInvoke(() => { ResultBackground = Brushes.Green; } )` from the Refill method itself instead. I probably have the syntax for that wrong, but you should be able to get the idea from there :)

Comment: @Rachel  Please see my above edit -- could I have had multiple bindings to the MenuItem OnSelected event to provoke two calls to the same command (with the second call undoing the first?)  Please glance at the xaml. Thanks.

Comment: Ugh!  Problem solved. Thanks to all for helping out. I'm kicking myself. In the delegate() method, just after refill() is called, there was a display refresh that was rebuilding the display--and destroying the screen where the green was displayed. The suggestion to use the Dispatcher is what lead to the discovery. Thanks again.

Comment: @AlanWayne Can you answer the question based up on your finding so that it can be closed?

Answer (score 1):

O.K., at risk of total embarrassment, here is the original code that was causing the blinking problem:

```
 OptionSubItems.Add(new MyMenuItem("Refill all current prescriptions", delegate()
        {
            CurrentViewModelDetails.ExecuteMenuCommand("RefillAllCurrentPrescriptions");
             CurrentViewModelDetails.RefreshDisplay(RxViews.PrescriptionList);
            DialogTitle = "Current Prescriptions";
        }));
```

The `RefreshDisplay()` method was rebuilding the display from the database and totally dropping the effects of the `refill()`--which explains why breakpoints placed on the `get{}` did not show any stack trace. The `get{}` were being called by the XAML when the new objects were created; there was no `set{}` involved. So the above code actually works fine (after I removed the offending line to be more concise for SO).

To give credit where credit is due, it was Rachel's suggestion that led to restudying the delegates, but thanks to all for the help.