# How to reach button objects which were created in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I made the buttons in UWP like this:

```
        <ItemsControl x:Name="tStack" Grid.Row="1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Name="iPT">
                <StackPanel x:Name="tStack1" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Height="64" Width="64"  ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Name}" Click="Button_Click" Tag="{Binding AppUri}" Background="{Binding Color}"  >
                    <StackPanel>

                        <Image Source="{Binding IconUri}"></Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

And now, after click each of them I want to set the background of the clicked one to some kind of color and set the color of background of the rest to transparent. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9069382/442444

Comment: I would suggest you keep the a `IsClicked` property in model and based on the model you can change the color using trigger or a converter.

Comment: Ok, but how to reset 'isClicked' property from other buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of your currently active button by saving it to a variable. Then you bind all of your buttons to the same Click-function. When any button is clicked you reset the active button's background, change your variable to the clicked button and set its background to your desired color.

```
Button activeButton;

void Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    activeButton.Background = null;
    activeButton = (Button)sender;
    activeButton.Background = Brushes.Blue;
}
```